# Spiliting values in query SQL

Tags: sql

I'm facing a problem right now.. what if the query itself contains code between bracket like `foo` and this `foo` is replaced with a declare-result value like `@foo`

when O want to print what's the container in `@foo` instead of 'foo' i should use `'@foo'` but sql reads it as '@foo' and ignores the `@` because it's between ' and '

In c# as usual, I do use "'"+@foo+"'" now in sql there's no ID for " so we use '

when i use `'''+@foo+'''` it does not read. although in c# we use something like \ between the brackets to get it done, sql does not read

What should I do in this case?

Image for the problem and query itself:

[image: Problem]

Comment: Keep the language clean. If you can't choose better names for your example text, then go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting to escape single quotes.

To do this you need to double them up!

```
DECLARE @foo char(1);
    SET @foo = 'A';

SELECT '''' As a_single_quote
     , '''''' As a_pair_of_single_quotes
     , '''' + 'TEST' + '''' As escaped_string
     , '''' + @foo + '''' As with_a_variable
```